# Divide quantities in order to get one quantity per row - python

Tags: python, dataframe, division

I have a dataframe with quantities and prices. I would like to get an dataframe with same prices vs quantity but only one quantity per line.

Dataframe:

```
Name | qty | Price
Apple | 3 | 3.50
Avocado | 2 | 1.50
```

Expected Output:

```
Name | qty| Price
Apple | 1 | 3.50
Apple | 1 | 3.50
Apple | 1 | 3.50
Avocado | 1 | 1.50
Avocado | 1 | 1.50
```

honestly don't know how to code this in a pythonic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`df.index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html), then set the `qty` to 1 for all rows.

```py
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['qty'])].reset_index(drop=True)
df['qty'] = 1
```

Output:

```
      Name  qty  Price
0    Apple    1    3.5
1    Apple    1    3.5
2    Apple    1    3.5
3  Avocado    1    1.5
4  Avocado    1    1.5
```